# Designing an efficient tool for query and comparison between #n-queries

Tags: python, algorithm, flask, sqlalchemy, bioinformatics

I am setting up a tool that compares samples. Each sample has 55,000 'genes' (the biology isn't important). I perform an initial query for samples that match a 'tissue type' then I want to know which genes in this set have a boolean-True>95%. I am doing this with a Flask application and SQLAlchemy database tables. Here are my models and current algorithm. When the number of samples is n=2, the function works fine, but when samples n>10, the process crashes.

The Sample table stores the name of the sample, some unimportant information, and a relationship to all 'genes' for that sample. The gene table simply stores the name of the gene and a boolean value. All samples have the same 55,000 genes and the GeneQual table has all 55,000 genes with information about them.

Models.py:

```py
class Sample(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    SRR_id = db.Column(db.String(10), index=True, unique=True)
    GSM_acc = db.Column(db.String(10))
    experiment_id = db.Column(db.String(10))
    tissue = db.Column(db.String(64))
    cell_type = db.Column(db.String(64))
    genes = db.relationship('Gene', backref='name', lazy='dynamic')
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<SRR_id {}>'.format(self.SRR_id)

class Gene(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    gene_id = db.Column(db.String(20), index=True)
    barcode = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    sample_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sample.id'))
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Gene_id {}>'.format(self.gene_id)

class GeneQual(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    gene_id = db.Column(db.String(20), index=True)
    symbol = db.Column(db.String(32))
    name = db.Column(db.String(32))
    location = db.Column(db.String(64))
```

function:

```py
samples = Sample.query.filter_by(tissues=tissue_type).all()
for i in range(len(samples)):
    samples[i] = samples[i].genes

results = []
for item in zip(*samples):
    sums = 0
    for i in range(len(item)):
        if item[i].barcode:
            sums += 1
    if sums >= (len(item)*0.95):
        results.append(item[0].gene_id)
```

I am open to any and all criticism, both on the set up of the database as well as the function. It could use some optimization to work when n-samples is larger.

Comment: Towards generating a mcve, if we only need 10 of something, but we need 50000 of something else, can that something else be initialized using the random module? And for those of us who use different but similar libraries, it might be easier if you provide the import statements for this.

Comment: why are you appending to results item[0].gene_id? shouldnt it be the sample_id?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter results by count of items in relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38637886/filter-results-by-count-of-items-in-relationship)